# JSON C# DeserializeObject Error with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, basecamp

I have a JSON string that I am getting from the BaseCamp API.  I know for a fact that the JSON is valid, however, I am not able to DeserializeObject using Newtonsoft.Json.

I get an error saying:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g.[1,2,3]) into type BaseCamp.Code.Projects+RootObject because the type requires a JSON objet (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
```

The JSON (Unformated What is returned from the API Minus the URL's Values)

```
[
    {
        "id":6656986,
        "name":"Physics Revamp",
        "description":"ISU department of physics website redesign",
        "archived":false,
        "is_client_project":true,
        "created_at":"2014-08-07T10:59:29.000-05:00",
        "updated_at":"2014-10-30T09:18:01.000-05:00",
        "trashed":false,
        "color":"2c5322",
        "draft":false,
        "template":false,
        "last_event_at":"2014-10-30T09:18:01.000-05:00",
        "starred":false,
        "url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "app_url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "id":7178664,
        "name":"Physics Videos",
        "description":"",
        "archived":false,
        "is_client_project":false,
        "created_at":"2014-10-02T08:34:46.000-05:00",
        "updated_at":"2014-10-23T08:40:17.000-05:00",
        "trashed":false,
        "color":"660099",
        "draft":false,
        "template":false,
        "last_event_at":"2014-10-23T08:40:17.000-05:00",
        "starred":false,
        "url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "app_url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "id":6685451,
        "name":"WZND Website 2014",
        "description":"",
        "archived":false,
        "is_client_project":true,
        "created_at":"2014-08-11T13:25:51.000-05:00",
        "updated_at":"2014-10-30T11:26:39.000-05:00",
        "trashed":false,
        "color":"3185c5",
        "draft":false,
        "template":false,
        "last_event_at":"2014-10-30T11:26:39.000-05:00",
        "starred":false,
        "url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "app_url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
]
```

My C# class:

```
public class Projects  
    {  
        public class RootObject  
        {  
            public int id { get; set; }  
            public string name { get; set; }  
            public string description { get; set; }  
            public bool archived { get; set; }  
            public bool is_client_project { get; set; }  
            public string created_at { get; set; }  
            public string updated_at { get; set; }  
            public bool trashed { get; set; }  
            public string color { get; set; }  
            public bool draft { get; set; }  
            public bool template { get; set; }  
            public string last_event_at { get; set; }  
            public bool starred { get; set; }  
            public string url { get; set; }  
            public string app_url { get; set; }  
        }  
    }
```

I am assuming something is wrong with the way my class is set up, but I can't see it.

Comment: How are you trying to deserialize your json? This seems to be a list of multiple RootObjects, so you have to make sure you're deserializing it into a list or array and not into a single RootObject.

Comment: var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Projects.RootObject>(response);  This has worked for me. In fact I just used it earlier in the app.  response is the json string that I get from the api.

Comment: This works if the json string only contains 1 RootObject, but in the given case it contains two. Therefor you need to deserialize it into a collection of RootObjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert to an array of `RootObject`:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Projects.RootObject[]>(response);
```

or list (or any other collection you want for that matter)...

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Projects.RootObject>>(response);
```

Comment: After doing that then how do I call the different values? Before I would just do json.name or json.id.  Which doesn't seem to be working anymore with this.

Comment: You can use `foreach (var item in json)` to access all items one by one, or `json[0]` to access first item, `json[1]` to access second item and so on...

Comment: So then what is the diffence between public class RootObject
        {
            public int expires_in { get; set; }
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string refresh_token { get; set; }
        } and the one I have up there?

I was able to use my old method for it.

Comment: Your class is *ONE* object. The `json` var above is a list/array with *MANY* objects.